# How to AND byte array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bit-manipulation, bitwise-and

So I was wondering if/how one might use the AND operation on a byte array in Java?

I've seen samples of how to use the AND operation with ints like so:

```
int bitmask = 0x000F;
int val = 0x2222;

// prints "2"
System.out.println(val & bitmask);
```

But say I have a byte Array like...

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[1];
```

and I want to AND it so that I remove the leftmost/fist bit in the array. I figure I'd use the mask `0x7F` but how would I AND that with the byte array?

Comment: You can't AND it as a whole, but you can go one by one: `byteArray[0] &= 0x7F`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to AND it so that I remove the leftmost/fist bit in the array

I assume with *remove* you mean *unset*, because you can't remove the first bit. It will always be there. If I am right, you can do this:

```
    byteArray[0] &= 127;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [bitwise and operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) would do the trick, it is simply `&`

This is the demo they present for masking:

```
class BitDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int bitmask = 0x000F;
        int val = 0x2222;
        // prints "2"
        System.out.println(val & bitmask);
    }
}
```